# Authinticate Azure api app using facebook, gmail, twitter and microsoft

Tags: asp.net, api, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure api app, i want to use facebook, twitter, google and microsoftaccount for authentication, what i have seen all points to AAD. I have setup all the configuration in the portal because of the nice documentation. Now im struggling to implement it in my webclient and xamarin forms. I have been searching all day long.. Can someone point out to an example. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I were starting such an app today, I'd definitely consider Azure AD B2C - the documentation page has a number of tutorials.

[Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/)

In lieu of that,or ASP.NET MVC have you seen:

[Code! MVC 5 App with Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn and Google OAuth2 Sign-on (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)

For ASP.NET Core:

[Enabling authentication using Facebook, Google and other external providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/)

For Xamarin Auth:

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.auth

Comment: I dont want to use AAD, i want to use facebook, google and twitter in my asp.net mvc. The problem they are no samples on how to do this